# Kamailio and Asterisk Inbound trunk for DID

Tags: asterisk, kamailio

I have configured inbound in trunk asterisk but dropping on Kamailio first...Kamailio and Asterisk are running on same machine.
Initial verification is done through IPAUTH in Kamailio and relayed to Asterisk

I am stuck in configuration of Trunk in Asterisk.

If I set HOST={PROVIDER IP} in asterisk then trunk does not work properly if I set HOST={LOCAL MACHINE IP} then it works but if I have to configure multiple trunks then it would be issue?

I need proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should mark provider ip in sip headers and read in asterisk via

SIPHEADER function

For outbound you can use outboundproxy= in sip.conf, but for inbound you can't do usual ip-based auth if you use kamailio.

Actually best way is NOT do auth at all on asterisk, but do all auth on kamailio. IP-based can be done via permission module.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using permissions module in Kamailio bur need to perform different actions in asterisk for different did / inbound trunk.

Comment: You have following options to put that info to asterisk: 1) sipheader 2) callerid/calleridname 3) in kamailio put info in database on invite.